# How to make my home BIND bypass ISP's DNS filtering?

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns, bind

everyone.

My ISP filters DNS requests. How exactly -- I don't know.

To avoid (or, at least, mitigate) this issue, I installed my own BIND on 192.168.3.1.

Here is my configuration:

```
logging {
        channel default_syslog {
            print-severity yes;
            syslog;
            severity notice;
            };
        };

acl homenets {
        192.168.0.0/16;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/named";
        /*
         * If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
         * to talk to, you might need to uncomment the query-source
         * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
         * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
         * port by default.
         */
        // query-source address * port 53;
        //Lockywolf's edition
        recursion yes;


        dnssec-validation auto;
        dnssec-enable yes;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        allow-recursion { homenets; };

};

key DHCP_UPDATER {
algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
secret "TOP_SECRET";
};


//
// a caching only nameserver config
//
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "caching-example/named.root";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/localhost.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/named.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};

// Lockywolf's added zones

zone "lwfhome" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/lwfhome.zone";
        allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
//      allow-transfer { ns1.namecheap.com; };
};
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone";
        allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
//      allow-transfer { ns1.namecheap.com; };
};
```

At least some of the configuration works fine. That is, I can resolve some names, and www.dnssec-failed.org returns a SERVFAIL.

BUT:

The filtered addresses are still being filtered.... but in a weird way.

When I ask for, say,
    dig youporn.com +trace +dnssec 
I get a totally bogus reply:

```
root@server:~# dig youporn.com +trace +dnssec

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P4 <<>> youporn.com +trace +dnssec
;; global options: +cmd
.                       463433  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       463433  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       517170  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20170226170000 20170213160000 61045 . ckPc/tLcnZ7g2jyLswmho73QA4WWPe3gUwyKZtbrxRZas70RSTS58P/Z KwTm+lJGJU+B6/9eOOerFv+qQ+hr9e4u/FNp3+bXDHnPYvsdEnxdr1r8 KMnjjw8vXjD8Qm3A8rLcMRD/kRFO6M8EmqZa9WvFSZHg9AF810c0Zuqf wocYLLbmT5JvuShyE0WBNks5a86vhxzNGjeKvoMg2op8yC3V0efSRZK2 uhcKupd0eSRrer3mNfjFLQFD/WGPMXYCFpPjxnwtDiXnevJ7FP2dkFWH rHHuxM10sXEUMvNKtLn7tJewzyJs5RUZdHiDYigsmKvaAsPy3x6GwDLF 7x8hjA==
;; Received 1044 bytes from 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1) in 0 ms

youporn.com.            1026    IN      A       213.167.39.27
;; Received 49 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 1 ms
```

Which is a lie, at least because the root servers don't keep any information about 'youporn.com'. Also the ip is wrong.

However, when I call:
    dig youporn.com +trace +dnssec +aaonly

The answer is surprisingly correct:

```
root@server:~# dig youporn.com +trace +dnssec +aaonly

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P4 <<>> youporn.com +trace +dnssec +aaonly
;; global options: +cmd
.                       463269  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       463269  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       517006  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20170226170000 20170213160000 61045 . ckPc/tLcnZ7g2jyLswmho73QA4WWPe3gUwyKZtbrxRZas70RSTS58P/Z KwTm+lJGJU+B6/9eOOerFv+qQ+hr9e4u/FNp3+bXDHnPYvsdEnxdr1r8 KMnjjw8vXjD8Qm3A8rLcMRD/kRFO6M8EmqZa9WvFSZHg9AF810c0Zuqf wocYLLbmT5JvuShyE0WBNks5a86vhxzNGjeKvoMg2op8yC3V0efSRZK2 uhcKupd0eSRrer3mNfjFLQFD/WGPMXYCFpPjxnwtDiXnevJ7FP2dkFWH rHHuxM10sXEUMvNKtLn7tJewzyJs5RUZdHiDYigsmKvaAsPy3x6GwDLF 7x8hjA==
;; Received 1044 bytes from 192.168.3.1#53(192.168.3.1) in 0 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20170226170000 20170213160000 61045 . UTYkZHzqLF8kqv9+7HVSKaMXwfLPMeLx3YMoU8ZWjTz1FiCjTOFzEp+2 s4hzjucEB7569Ppzru+0UuzTm9tumkSUJoGhBLdfOUi4b6dKTSGb3Ybn GApoSrTGMnMGrtiIApYLhdQ1a9KZ6PaarPwbpOQ6Td+8ClqSCYK3/xdA nyUXCd1qdfYFyC3WPyouoDZsK+Ahc9B2VMnevfB561j5eX2JxNzqnI8a YaVUTrMzKhIL1rK51fRboXcdkVVmJN8eKV/ulXx73W2P2qGNeuuyy9RV MuAFrclZjzrPx2l7AB6Xpy7b9r7SmONc1ekD3RFcXBTF2zEHeepwRSzg bR1L9w==
;; Received 863 bytes from 199.7.91.13#53(d.root-servers.net) in 57 ms

youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns1.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns2.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns3.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      ns4.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.net.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.com.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.org.
youporn.com.            172800  IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.biz.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A  NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170218054619 20170211043619 31697 com. CEbyhokcC5jQBv+v5W2XQt6rpLb6sLXLpAiOf34X2grUTdlMQfbUInmV MDwYVpuK+lK/CSwRrCWvP3k/7QqwsC4AkveIoi3WMfvAZMTkhMV6an2x FH3jeym2vFA3XSYTBaLIE7ut/MzrZci5qfdGqufBB04OcKLhKNKLRI1J HiI=
PUFL8VGRQ3N4TC6QV3G2R207UO9KDLM8.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - PUFN28L13OQTHBV8S731Q0AG2FJBS4QT  NS DS RRSIG
PUFL8VGRQ3N4TC6QV3G2R207UO9KDLM8.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170220053808 20170213042808 31697 com. wtNzw5INtkN3aUd90oZJX/i/eQGSb4WG2zcXtIY1QXP1YddWOUhNcU8x kynuuaGJrFPQdskDnDs8w61xhBAL7r4VDii/vAfCIV65KFxHcSL1/GMB KRY5dnUyUfCNnC88zxoIEUqdmiQCLgjpHPgZ1WcaMKOHTTaMY5L0IPeW WXo=
;; Received 885 bytes from 192.54.112.30#53(h.gtld-servers.net) in 25 ms

youporn.com.            300     IN      A       31.192.120.44
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.biz.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      ns2.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.org.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      ns1.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      ns3.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.com.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      ns4.p44.dynect.net.
youporn.com.            86400   IN      NS      sdns3.ultradns.net.
;; Received 264 bytes from 204.13.250.44#53(ns2.p44.dynect.net) in 55 ms
```

I don't understand this configuration. If the ISP is smart enough to fake the signature of the root servers, then why does the last command work?

If they cannot do that, then why do I see fake reply for 'youporn.com' from 'root-servers'. I'd expect the trust hierarchy work up until youporn's own nameservers, and expect to receive a fake ip from them (hijacked by the MITM), but no, they already manage to hijack the very first step.

Could someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: You can try without BIND and just query Google DNS (8.8.8.8). If that doesn’t work you need to use some sort of encrypted DNS tunnel or an alternate name resolution protocol. There are some available for those of us living in not-so-free places, though I can’t recommend anything specifically.

Comment: Have a look at newer standards: DNS over TLS and soon DNS over HTTPS. You can then configure a recursive nameserver in some safe network place and contact it only through TLS. See the unbound and stubby software.

Answer (score 1):

The hijacking usually isn't as specific as you think. The ISP probably doesn't *care* which DNS server you're querying – they intercept all UDP packets to port 53, and as long as the query was for `youporn.com` a fake reply is returned.

Except, that is, when you set additional flags which confuse the ISP's filter and make it pass the original query through. For example, the AA bit in queries is actually nonstandard (the option in dig is merely [a leftover](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/dnsext/current/msg10561.html)), so perhaps the ISP's filter considers these queries malformed and doesn't scan them? (Similarly, in some places only UDP is filtered while making DNS queries over TCP works fine.)

The ISP doesn't fake any signature. Notice how the fake replies don't *have* one – they only list a fake A record but no RRSIG.

(Even if there was a signature, dig doesn't actually validate those – its `+dnssec` option merely tells the server to *include* the signatures in the first place, but dig doesn't do anything with them. You need something like `drill -S` or `drill -TD` to perform client-side validation.)

Regardless, DNSSEC can only alert you about fake data – it cannot *prevent* the data from being faked. The most common ways of bypassing DNS filtering involve encryption – namely, DNS-over-TLS (supported by Unbound) or DNSCrypt (has its own proxy daemon).

Comment: Thanks, this is explanatory. However, concerning Unbound. I'd like my BIND to (eventually) serve as an authoritative NS for my own zone. I guess, it won't work with dns-over-tls, will it? Since it needs to be contacted from outer Internet.

Comment: @VladimirNikishkin mixing authoritative and recursive functions in the same nameserver is not a good idea. Try to split them apart.